# Is there any tool for command line debugging on linux, instead of gdb?

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, command

Is there any tool for command line debugging on linux, instead of gdb?

GDB sometimes make me feel tired, because I am not that familiar with it. Just want to find another way to do debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `gdb`, try `gdbtui` for a semi-graphical interface.

For a full GUI, try one of these front-ends for [gdb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Debugger):

[gdb] does not contain its own graphical user interface, and defaults to a command-line interface. Several front-ends have been built for it, such as UltraGDB, Xxgdb, Data Display Debugger (DDD), Nemiver, KDbg, Xcode debugger, GDBtk/Insight and the HP Wildebeest Debugger GUI (WDB GUI). IDEs such as Codelite, Code::Blocks, Dev-C++, Geany, GNAT Programming Studio (GPS), KDevelop, Qt Creator, Lazarus, MonoDevelop, Eclipse, NetBeans and VisualStudio (see VS AddIn Gallery) can interface with GDB. GNU Emacs has a "GUD mode" and tools for VIM exist (e.g. clewn.) These offer facilities similar to debuggers found in IDEs.

Answer (score 1):

Other than GDB there is [LLDB](http://lldb.llvm.org) which is based on clang and LLVM. It uses different syntax than GDB and tends to be a little easier to script. Though it lacks some features of GDB such as remote debugging.